# Firefox flex bug applied to buttons?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to apply `flex` to a button but on Firefox I'm having a problem that on Chrome doesn't happens.

This is my CSS:

```
.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

As you can see in the fiddle, the "caret" word is moved to a new line, but it happens only if the element is a `<button>` tag, `<div>` works as expected.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbLMGx

Is this a Firefox bug or is there some extra CSS I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, looks like "Mr Firefox" doesn't like the idea...

> `<button>` is not implementable (by browsers) in pure CSS, so they are a
>   bit of a black box, from the perspective of CSS. This means that they
>   don't necessarily react in the same way that e.g. a `<div>` would.
>
> This isn't specific to flexbox -- e.g. we don't render scrollbars if
>   you put "overflow:scroll" on a button, and we don't render it as a
>   table if you put "display:table" on it.
>
> Stepping back even further, this isn't specific to `<button>`. Consider
>   `<fieldset>` and `<table>` which also have special rendering behavior:
>   `data:text/html,<fieldset style="display:flex"><div>abc</div><div>def</div>`
>   `data:text/html,<table style="display:flex"><div>abc</div><div>def</div>`
>
> In these cases, Chrome agrees with us and disregards the "flex"
>   display mode. (as revealed by the fact that  "abc" and "def" end up
>   being stacked vertically). The fact that they happen to do what you're
>   expecting on  is likely just due to an
>   implementation detail.
>
> In Gecko's button implementation, we hardcode `<button>` (and
>   `<fieldset>`, and `<table>`) as having a specific frame class (and hence,
>   a specific way of laying out the child elements), regardless of the
>   "display" property.
>
> If you want to reliably have the children reliably arranged in a
>   particular layout mode in a cross-browser fashion, your best bet is to
>   use a wrapper-div inside the button, just as you would need to inside
>   of a `<table>` or a `<fieldset>`.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869